# Get attribute value of elements by the value of another attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It's the first time I use d3.js.
I have a variable `i` (integer) and an html like that:

```html
<svg width="445" height="430">
        <g transform="translate(150,50)">
            <defs>...</defs>
            <g class="rowLabels">...</g>
            <g class="colLabels">...</g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.60" data-r="0" data-c="0" class="cell cr0 cc0" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="0" y="0" fill="rgb(144, 220, 162)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="95.80" data-r="0" data-c="1" class="cell cr0 cc1" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="17" y="0" fill="rgb(127, 215, 169)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="95.90" data-r="0" data-c="2" class="cell cr0 cc2" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="34" y="0" fill="rgb(129, 216, 168)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.60" data-r="0" data-c="3" class="cell cr0 cc3" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="51" y="0" fill="rgb(144, 220, 162)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.80" data-r="0" data-c="4" class="cell cr0 cc4" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="68" y="0" fill="rgb(149, 222, 160)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.50" data-r="0" data-c="5" class="cell cr0 cc5" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="85" y="0" fill="rgb(142, 220, 163)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.50" data-r="0" data-c="6" class="cell cr0 cc6" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="102" y="0" fill="rgb(142, 220, 163)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.70" data-r="0" data-c="7" class="cell cr0 cc7" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="119" y="0" fill="rgb(146, 221, 161)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.30" data-r="0" data-c="8" class="cell cr0 cc8" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="136" y="0" fill="rgb(138, 218, 165)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.10" data-r="0" data-c="9" class="cell cr0 cc9" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="153" y="0" fill="rgb(134, 217, 166)" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1px;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.30" data-r="0" data-c="10" class="cell cr0 cc10" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="170" y="0" fill="rgb(138, 218, 165)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.10" data-r="0" data-c="11" class="cell cr0 cc11" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="187" y="0" fill="rgb(134, 217, 166)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="96.10" data-r="0" data-c="12" class="cell cr0 cc12" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="204" y="0" fill="rgb(134, 217, 166)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="95.74" data-r="0" data-c="13" class="cell cr0 cc13" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="221" y="0" fill="rgb(126, 215, 169)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="94.71" data-r="0" data-c="14" class="cell cr0 cc14" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="238" y="0" fill="rgb(110, 207, 177)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="93.43" data-r="0" data-c="15" class="cell cr0 cc15" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="255" y="0" fill="rgb(112, 194, 179)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="93.33" data-r="0" data-c="16" class="cell cr0 cc16" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="272" y="0" fill="rgb(112, 193, 179)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="97.50" data-r="1" data-c="0" class="cell cr1 cc0" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="0" y="17" fill="rgb(164, 226, 154)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="98.80" data-r="1" data-c="1" class="cell cr1 cc1" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="17" y="17" fill="rgb(191, 234, 143)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="" data-r="1" data-c="2" class="cell cr1 cc2" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="34" y="17" fill="url(#pattern-stripes)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="93.20" data-r="1" data-c="3" class="cell cr1 cc3" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="51" y="17" fill="rgb(113, 192, 179)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            <g>
                <rect data-value="98.20" data-r="1" data-c="4" class="cell cr1 cc4" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="68" y="17" fill="rgb(178, 230, 148)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
            </g>
            </g>
    </svg>
```

I want to select all the `rect` element with `data-r` attribute `= i` and put their `data-value` attribute inside the array `arr`.

So, for example, if `i = 0` then `arr = [96.60, 95.80, 95.90, 96.60, ...]`. `arr` contains only `data-value` with `data-r = 0`.

How can I do that?
I try:

```
console.log(d3.selectAll('.data-r' + i).attr('data-value'));
console.log((d3.select('.data-r') == i)).attr('data-value');
console.log((d3.select('.data-r') = i)).attr('data-value');
```

but nothing works.

I prefer not to use jQuery, but if it's necessary ok.

Thanks!

Comment: You have no 'g' elements with those attributes, you have 'rect' elements with those attributes.

Comment: @Codeer I delete image and I add code

Comment: @RyanWilson You are right. It was a type error when I wrote the question. I edit the main message

Comment: @ComeDown Added an answer below using plain javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `d3.selectAll` with a CSS attribute selection:

```
d3.selectAll("rect[data-r='" + i + "']")
```

Have in mind that, in the three attempts described in your question, you're selecting a *class*.

Then, using a `selection.each`, just push the values in the array with a getter:

```
selection.each(function() {
    arr.push(d3.select(this).attr("data-value"))
});
```

Or just (thanks to [@altocumulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922451/get-attribute-value-of-elements-by-the-value-of-another-attribute/49922770?noredirect=1#comment86863802_49922770)):

```
selection.each(function() {
    arr.push(this.dataset.value)
});
```

Which is a good alternative, since D3 getters are slower.

Here is a demo using your SVG and `i = 0`:

```js
var i = "0";
var arr = [];
var sel = d3.selectAll("rect[data-r='" + i + "']")
  .each(function() {
    arr.push(this.dataset.value)
  })

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="445" height="430">
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.60" data-r="0" data-c="0" class="cell cr0 cc0" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="0" y="0" fill="rgb(144, 220, 162)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="95.80" data-r="0" data-c="1" class="cell cr0 cc1" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="17" y="0" fill="rgb(127, 215, 169)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="95.90" data-r="0" data-c="2" class="cell cr0 cc2" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="34" y="0" fill="rgb(129, 216, 168)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.60" data-r="0" data-c="3" class="cell cr0 cc3" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="51" y="0" fill="rgb(144, 220, 162)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.80" data-r="0" data-c="4" class="cell cr0 cc4" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="68" y="0" fill="rgb(149, 222, 160)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.50" data-r="0" data-c="5" class="cell cr0 cc5" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="85" y="0" fill="rgb(142, 220, 163)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.50" data-r="0" data-c="6" class="cell cr0 cc6" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="102" y="0" fill="rgb(142, 220, 163)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.70" data-r="0" data-c="7" class="cell cr0 cc7" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="119" y="0" fill="rgb(146, 221, 161)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.30" data-r="0" data-c="8" class="cell cr0 cc8" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="136" y="0" fill="rgb(138, 218, 165)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.10" data-r="0" data-c="9" class="cell cr0 cc9" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="153" y="0" fill="rgb(134, 217, 166)" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1px;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.30" data-r="0" data-c="10" class="cell cr0 cc10" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="170" y="0" fill="rgb(138, 218, 165)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.10" data-r="0" data-c="11" class="cell cr0 cc11" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="187" y="0" fill="rgb(134, 217, 166)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="96.10" data-r="0" data-c="12" class="cell cr0 cc12" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="204" y="0" fill="rgb(134, 217, 166)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="95.74" data-r="0" data-c="13" class="cell cr0 cc13" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="221" y="0" fill="rgb(126, 215, 169)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="94.71" data-r="0" data-c="14" class="cell cr0 cc14" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="238" y="0" fill="rgb(110, 207, 177)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="93.43" data-r="0" data-c="15" class="cell cr0 cc15" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="255" y="0" fill="rgb(112, 194, 179)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="93.33" data-r="0" data-c="16" class="cell cr0 cc16" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="272" y="0" fill="rgb(112, 193, 179)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="97.50" data-r="1" data-c="0" class="cell cr1 cc0" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="0" y="17" fill="rgb(164, 226, 154)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="98.80" data-r="1" data-c="1" class="cell cr1 cc1" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="17" y="17" fill="rgb(191, 234, 143)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="" data-r="1" data-c="2" class="cell cr1 cc2" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="34" y="17" fill="url(#pattern-stripes)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="93.20" data-r="1" data-c="3" class="cell cr1 cc3" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="51" y="17" fill="rgb(113, 192, 179)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect data-value="98.20" data-r="1" data-c="4" class="cell cr1 cc4" width="17" height="17" rx="4" ry="4" x="68" y="17" fill="rgb(178, 230, 148)" style="stroke: none;"></rect>
        </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: It's going to be shorter and faster if you replace the line inside the`.each()` with just `arr.push(this.dataset.value);`. *Plus*, as you are the teaching guy, it helps to spread the knowledge about the correct use of the data-* attributes and the `dataset` property.

Answer (score 0):

Plain Vanilla javascript:

```
//Grab all rect elements
const rects = document.getElementsByTagName('rect');
let myArray = [];

//Iterate your rect elements, if the element's attribute data-r === i push
//it's data-value attribute value into array
for(let x = 0; x < rects.length; x++){
    if(rects[x].getAttribute("data-r") === i.toString()){
        myArray.push(rects[x].getAttribute("data-value"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .querySelectorAll():

```
const i = "0";
document.querySelectorAll(`rect[data-r='${i}'`);
```